# Exclude specific subfolder from tree

Tags: bash

```
me@s:/tmp$ mkdir -p test/raw test/{a,b,c}/data/x
me@s:/tmp$ tree test/
test/
├── a
│   └── data
│       └── x
├── b
│   └── data
│       └── x
├── c
│   └── data
│       └── x
└── raw
```

I need to exclude test/raw and test/b/data but tree -I only want folder names:

```
me@s:/tmp$ tree test -I 'raw|b/data'
test
├── a
│   └── data
│       └── x
├── b
│   └── data
│       └── x
└── c
    └── data
        └── x
```

Without the `b/data` that exclude all data folders:

```
me@s:/tmp$ tree test -I 'raw|data'
test
├── a
├── b
└── c

me@s:/tmp$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options `-P` and `-I` of the `tree` command, only work on the file-names and not on the path-names of the file [1].

Having hat said, you could use `grep` to extract the wanted information:

```
$ tree -f test | grep -vE '(raw|b/data)'
test
├── test/a
│   └── test/a/data
│       └── test/a/data/x
├── test/c
│   └── test/c/data
│       └── test/c/data/x
```

Here, we make use of the flag `-f` which prints the relative path-name with respect to the directory `test`. The `grep` command does the rest.

As you notice, the exclusion of `raw` does not allow for a clean tree-output as you have spurious `|`'s .

---

**Notes:**

1. in Linux, everything is a file.

Answer (score 1):

As of the current version of [`tree`](https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree) (v2.0.2), this is not possible.

The pattern is applied to the filename only (the `d_name` member of the a `struct dirent`).

See [here](https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/blob/master/tree.c#L720), the `getinfo` function gets called from [here](https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/blob/master/tree.c#L812).